# Unable to Perform Graceful Shutdown of Asyncio App after a KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, python-asyncio, event-loop

I am having trouble letting my `asyncio` app shutdown gracefully when the user creates a `KeyboardInterrupt` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Why is it still not working properly despite using `try... except KeyboardInterrupt`? It still shows a `traceback` and something about a `Unclosed AIOKafkaProducer`.

```py
import asyncio
from aiokafka import AIOKafkaProducer


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.producer = None

    async def start(self):
        self.producer = AIOKafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="localhost:29092")
        await self.producer.start()

        self.loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.loop())
        await asyncio.gather(*[self.loop_task])

    async def stop(self):
        self.loop_task.cancel()
        await self.producer.stop()

    async def loop(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def main():
    foo = Foo()
    try:
        await foo.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(
            "Attempting graceful shutdown, press Ctrl+C+ again to exit...", flush=True
        )
        await foo.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Error messages after pressing pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/test.py", line 37, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1854, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.9/selectors.py", line 469, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
Unclosed AIOKafkaProducer
producer: <aiokafka.producer.producer.AIOKafkaProducer object at 0x7f643c0d0c40>
```

---

**Adding `try...except` around `main()`**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
```

This gave the same traceback

Comment: If you look at the stack trace at which point of your code the error is from you can see its `asyncio.run(main())` have you tried putting the try / except around that part?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Tried putting try / except there, but still the same traceback with no additional information. Updated question with new code.